# Implementing a numerical integration method in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a numerical integral calculator as my first Python project. The method takes a starting x value, a delta x value, and a set of y values and returns a lower and an upper bound. I am expecting the result of the numerical integration to converge as dx gets smaller, but it is getting larger.

I am trying to integrate an exponential from 0 to 1 and get the result to converge to 1/3 as dx gets smaller. Currently a dx of 0.1 gives me bounds of (0.14000000000000004, 0.17200000000000004). A dx of 0.01 has bounds of (0.30894500000000014, 0.313747).

Here is my code:

```
class Linear:
    """Creates a linear function from 2 points"""
    def __init__(self, x0, y0, x1, y1):
        self.__x0 = x0
        self.__y0 = y0
        self.__x1 = x1
        self.__y1 = y1
        self.__a = ((y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0))
        self.__b = y0 - (self.__a * x0)

    def fun(self, x):
        return self.__a * x + self.__b


def integrate(x0, dx, data):
    if len(data) < 3:
        raise ValueError("data passed to integrate doesn't have enough data")
    else:
        i, lb, ub = 2, 0, 0
        while i < len(data):
            y0, y1, y2 = data[i - 2], data[i - 1], data[i]
            lin = Linear(x0, y0, x0 + dx + dx, y2)
            lin_delta = lin.fun(x0 + dx)
            if y1 < lin_delta:
                if y0 < y1:
                    lb += (y0 * dx)
                    ub += ((((y1 - y0) * dx) / 2) + (y0 * dx))
                else:
                    lb += (y1 * dx)
                    ub += ((((y0 - y1) * dx) / 2) + (y1 * dx))
            else:
                if y0 < y1:
                    ub += (y1 * dx)
                    lb += ((((y1 - y0) * dx) / 2) + (y0 * dx))
                else:
                    ub += (y0 * dx)
                    lb += ((((y0 - y1) * dx) / 2) + (y1 * dx))
            i += 1
            x0 += dx

    return lb, ub


if __name__ == '__main__':
    j = 0
    d = []
    dxj = 0.1

    while j < (1/dxj):
        d += [(j * dxj) * (j * dxj)]
        j += 1

    print(d)
    print(integrate(0, dxj, d))
```

Also, what is the best way to avoid name collisions with counters like i?

Comment: "what is the best way to avoid name collisions with counters like i" - one option is splitting the code in several functions with their local scopes

Comment: Any reference to the numerical method used? `d` or `data` seems like a list of `x` values, but you do `y0, y1, y2 = data[i - 2], data[i - 1], data[i]`. `x0` is never changed, shouldn't both `x` and `y` values be updated for each `i`?

Comment: You are right! It still diverges after updating x0

Comment: The code I have is my py file. I'm using pycharm if that makes a difference.

Comment: I assume you cannot use numpy or scipy?

Comment: I am trying to get familiar with python, so would prefer not to use numpy or scipy for the time being

Comment: So now it converges nicely to 1/3, but the bounds are not actually bounds, right? In that case, I think the reference / description of the method is needed..

Comment: You mean like docstrings?

Comment: What is the point of things like `self.__x0 = x0`? Those aren't actually used in any meaningful way in the class definition. Unless you plan to add some methods which have recourse to them, it is just wasted lines.

Comment: I figured it out thanks to Jan. While writing my docstrings, I realized the last value wasn't ever bounded.

Comment: You are right John, I'm not sure what compelled me to put those lines.